# Postfix not starting on boot

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, boot

So I run Debian 6 and have installed and configured postfix...the problem is postfix starts normally when I start it with:

```
sudo service postfix start
```

but if I reboot the server it won't. I have checked the log and this is the error it gives:

```
Jun 10 06:18:51 VPS postfix[1567]: fatal: the postfix command must not run as a set-uid process
```

How can I fix this?

When I do:

```
update-rc.d postfix start 20 2 3 4 5
```

I get this output:

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: warning: postfix stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/vzquota, ../rc0.d/S03vzquota): File exists
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/vzquota, ../rc1.d/S03vzquota): File exists
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/vzquota, ../rc2.d/S03vzquota): File exists
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/vzquota, ../rc3.d/S03vzquota): File exists
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/vzquota, ../rc4.d/S03vzquota): File exists
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/vzquota, ../rc5.d/S03vzquota): File exists
insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/vzquota, ../rc6.d/S03vzquota): File exists
```

Comment: How did you install postfix? Manually or by repos?

Comment: Do You have sendmail installed?

Comment: Bart by repo, @Alan no sendmail is not installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix/sendmail may not be owned by root and/or set-uid bit enabled.

http://www.gti.net/mirrors/postfix/faq.html#nosuid

Postfix should be owned by dedicated user.

I think you should re-install completely postfix, there may be other configuration issues.

try

```
apt-get --purge remove postfix
```

or

```
aptitude remove postfix*
```

Then follow this [article](http://wiki.debian.org/Postfix) to install it in correct way.

If problem if that it not start at startup try to configure service as follows:

```
update-rc.d postfix start 20 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Done all that...the error is still there...

Comment: can you do ls -l on sendmail and postfix binary and share it with us?

Comment: rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9500 May 4 2011 /usr/sbin/postfix, sendmail is not installed